# Multisite Change from domain.com to sub.newdomain.com

Tags: plugins, multisite

I want to create a new staging instance on another server for my multisite installation. I've used UpdraftPlus (Premium)

The sites on the production side are like this:
Primary Site: https://domain.de (actually working site)
Sub Site: https://dev1.domain.net/ (nothing really here)

**Steps**
0) Create Subdomain - staging.domainnew.me

1. Create WordPress Site (Clean)
2. Configure it for Multisite
3. Migrate Mulisite using Updraft

Now I have a staging site but can't get this https://domain.de to work.

Obviously https://domain.de has to change to something.

What should I do?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know UpdraftPlus: it's a backup and restore plugin? If it's restored a site and the site isn't working you should probably ask them for help directly, particularly if you have premium support.

Comment: If you want to try and diagnose why your new multisite isn't working though, can you give us more details? What happens when you go to domain.de? Is the DNS set up correctly, does your web server recognise the virtual host and route it to WordPress correctly, does WordPress recognise the domain, does it serve some files / the wrong files / something else? Is there anything in your web server error logs? etc.

Comment: domain.de is on the production site, it's up and runnning. I've created a staging out of it on another server. 

This might sound like a silly question but I have to change domain.de to something else.

Can I just create a subdomain on the same staging server and change the settings from my network to this?

Comment: Anyway, appearantly I did everything right right up to the point that I haven't changed the old site URL in the Database. That did the trick. Pretty obvious thing.

Comment: UPDATE ChangeWithWPPrefixForSubsiteTarget_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';UPDATE ChangeWithWPPrefixForSubsiteTarget_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');UPDATE ChangeWithWPPrefixForSubsiteTarget_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com'); UPDATE ChangeWithWPPrefixForSubsiteTarget_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');